# I can't select font-awesome element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-awesome

COMPLETE CODE IN FIDDLE LINE 36 JAVASCRIPT IS ISSUE PART https://jsfiddle.net/ybp7gtup/7/

I want to change the color of the icon using js or jquery as I am using form validation to change color on user behaviour. I can't seem to select the `<i>` in the DOM, can anyone advise?

html:

```
<div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 icons-div">
        <div class="row">
            <i class="fa fa-user fa-color"></i>
         </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
select:invalid {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px red;
}

select:valid {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #449d44;
}

.fa {
    font-size: 3em;
}

.fa-calendar {
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

.hide-div .fa {
    font-size: 1em;
}

.red {
    color: #FFA5A5;
}

.green {
    color: #449d44;
}
```

jquery:

```
$('.fa-color').addClass('red');
```

Comment: Are you sure that jQuery statement is being executed?

Comment: yes indeed because when I do "$('div').addClass('red');" all text in all div's turn red

Comment: You are trying to select all elements that have class `a` and add class `b` to them. It is pointless. Why aren't you just adding whatever styles you have in class `b` to class `a`?

Comment: Is your jquery statement inside $(document).ready?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu the classes to change color need to have a specific class name of fa-color

Comment: .red {
    color: #FFA5A5 !important;
} try this ? nothing ?

Comment: My genuinely helpful advice to you would be to take some time and read the basics about how classes and CSS work, before wrestling with `jQuery`. It will save you loads of time.

Comment: @Nora yes I have tried that also

Comment: Your jquery works fine check here:  https://jsfiddle.net/ybp7gtup/6/

Comment: @HastaPasta thats great it was working however I've added my complete code which is using angular and now it isn't working so maybe you can have look? https://jsfiddle.net/ybp7gtup/7/ line 36

Comment: You should include angular and your controller in the fiddle. You can try wrapping this line in $timeout(function(){ $('.fa-color').addClass('red'); }) But in general, you should refactor the controller and separate DOM manipulation in directives

Comment: @Nora I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption that the `jQuery` is not working is wrong. Your problem is that your selector is (most likely) weaker than the one applying the `color` property on the element when it has both `fa-color` and `red` classes. This should work:

```
.fa-color.red {
    color: #FFA5A5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with to edit the fa-color class ( no need to use jquery )

```
.fa-color{
   color: #FFA5A5 !important;
}
```

Comment: COMPLETE CODE IN FIDDLE LINE 36 JAVASCRIPT IS ISSUE PART https://jsfiddle.net/ybp7gtup/7/

Comment: I understand that you want to colored the user icon right ?

Comment: yes using jquery as I want to change the color when form is invalid/valid

Answer (score 1):

Just add an ID. and

```
<div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 icons-div">
    <div class="row">
        <i class="fa fa-user" id = "color_guy"></i>
     </div>
</div>
```

then with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#color_guy').addClass('red');
)};
```

This should work!

Comment: It will work in one case. What if there are 20? Why limit something that will work for an infinite number of elements to only one? Only because `id`s are stronger selectors than `classes`? You can build strong selectors without `id`s, too.

Comment: COMPLETE CODE IN FIDDLE LINE 36 JAVASCRIPT IS ISSUE PART https://jsfiddle.net/ybp7gtup/7/

Answer (score 1):

It was weird, but jquery would randomly not select certain elements (or that is what *appeared* to be happening). Regular js would select the element, and a few times I just plowed on, but in one case I really wanted to use jQuery's toggle(). I couldn't even figure out how to search for an answer until it dawned on me that it wasn't random at all, but always font awesome classes where jQuery failed (but produced no errors).

After struggling all day with this, I stumbled across this article that seems to address this issue. It sounds like font awesome is affecting something in the element, which makes the jquery statements not work as expected. I believe the work-arounds given in the article are going to work, but i haven't tested them yet.

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/jquery

ABE:
So, the article says that the font-awesome script seeks out the  tags with the fontawesome classes (fas, fa, etc) and REPLACES them with , so it suggested adding an extra js reference that would cause fontawesome to NEST the  tags inside the original  tags. Sounded like a winner, but it didn't work for me.

Then I found [THIS article on fontawesome's site](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements) that shows how to use fontawesome via css pseudoelements, and I thought that would work, but it did not.

Frankly, at this point, I'm ready to just use icon images. I'm not very good at javascript or jquery and this is way more complicated than it seems like it should be.

*** UPDATE ***

I was not preceding the class name selector with a "." in the jQuery. so, for example, I was writing $('icon') when I should have written $('.icon'). Man, like a day and half wasted over a stupid dot. EVERY method works fine if the class name selector is typed in correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Tested your code in a jsfiddle, it works.
You might have forgotten to include JQuery into your document header.
For example:
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>`

Comment: COMPLETE CODE IN FIDDLE LINE 36 JAVASCRIPT IS ISSUE PART https://jsfiddle.net/ybp7gtup/7/